# Pagination design using HTML tables and Ajax

Tags: html, ajax, pagination, html-table

What is the best design approach for displaying paginated results in an HTML table, dynamically repopulated using Ajax requests?

I am using PHP, jQuery and Bootstrap, but that should not matter much for this question. At the moment I am thinking of the following structure, as an example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- Populated by Ajax -->
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Paginator HTML generated server-side -->
<ul class="paginator">
    <li><a href="?p=1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="?p=1">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="?p=1">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="?p=2">2</a></li>
    ... etc ...
    <li><a href="?p=3">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="?p=20">Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

This works well, but the cons of this design is that I need to update the paginator `ul` as follows:

- Check if I need the first/prev/next/last controls and attach/detach them (can't show/hide here because the rounded corners are applied to `li:first-child a` and `li:last-child a` in Bootstrap)
- Move the `active` class to the correct element
- Server-side generated paginator needs to be updated client-side: possible duplicating of code

An alternative is to put this `ul` in a `<tfoot></tfoot>` section within the table. This means the paginator is updated server-side, which is fine and dandy. But then I have the following cons:

- Change the Ajax request to return all of the three `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` sections, since I'd have to `$.load()` the `table` element, instead of the `tbody` element.
- Reassign the click handler on the paginator links to be dealt with JavaScript after `$.load`ing (the links are there for progressive enhancement)
- Possible flickering of the paginator part

**What would you do?**

Answer (score 0):

In case of populating a table, I use a lot jQuery datatables plugin, it offer's an Ajax solution with sorting, searching and pagination:

```
http://www.datatables.net/
```

It comes with a bootstrap theme, too.

Take a look at AJAX and SERVER SIDE PROCESSING subjects in their site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is not an answer, but I will check out the datatables plugin and see how they structure their HTML and where they put their paginator element, and come back here.